# problem regarding copying/taking a node from the binary tree

Tags: javascript, queue, binary-tree, javascript-objects

question(language used - js) - when you copy a node from the binary tree, are the whole branches below that node (you know binary tree node has properties `left` and `right`, below them, are more nodes.) also get copied inside the variable? Well... `node` is an object in the binary tree...and `objects` are `reference values`, so I am guessing that the same `node` of the tree is enqueued there, instead of `copy of that node`.

I am trying to do `breadthFirstSearch` in the binary tree, where I have to put the `node` of the tree in the `queue`. I want to know that, when I `enqueue` the `node` of the `binary tree` in `queue`, is the copy of that specific `node` along with its `keys` or `properties`(as we know) gets added to the `queue` or only reference to that `node` is added? Because if that specific node is copied, and the tree has 1000s of nodes in it, then the whole branch below that `node` might get copied too(since I don't know if this actually happens or not)....which is very very bad for performance and memory. If it's only referenced to that node, then it's completely fine as I am not copying the whole branch of the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript assigns **objects** and **arrays** by reference, which means a given object or array can be assigned to any number of variables without duplicating it.
Besides, objects and arrays are **mutable**, which means you can modify their contents after they have been created.

For instance:

```
a = [1,2,3];     // a is a reference to a freshly created array
b = a;           // b is a second reference to the same array
a.pop();         // a is used to remove the last element of the underlying array
console.log (b); // b is also affected
```

output:

```
Array [ 1, 2 ] // through `a` we modified the contents of `b`.
```

The main advantage of mutability is efficiency, as you pointed out.
On the other hand, working with mutable objects is tricky, as you are left in charge of guaranteeing the consistency of your references (in layman's terms, you are constantly at risk of inadvertently clobbering the contents of some 'b' through some 'a').
Since JavaScript has a very limited notion of [variable typing](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-php-mysql/9781449337452/ch13s06.html), there is no simple way to tell which identifier(s) allow to access and modify a given piece of data at some point.
Defining a notion of equality is also difficult: are we talking about equality of references (a and b referencing the same underlying object) or equality of contents (a and b referencing two distinct objects that happen to hold identical data)?
This pitfall is the source of countless puzzling bugs.
To make matters worse, built-in methods offer a mix of approaches. For instance, some chainable Array methods (`filter`, `map`, `reduce`, `find`) return new arrays, others (`pop`/`push`, `shift`/`unshift`, `splice`, `sort`) modify the array in place.

JavaScript is an old language which evolved through 6 versions while maintaining upward compatibility, ending up with a collection of mechanisms that are very difficult to specify in a rigorous, deterministic way. This is why the official specification of the version implemented in current browsers (ECMA 6.0) is, unfortunately, anything but educational material.
I doubt a language learner would get much benefit from reading it beyond the initial [overview](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-overview), which doesn't dwell into details.
Unless you want to specialize in JS and tackle the spec yourself, you'll have to rely on gloss by bloggers, like [this one](https://medium.com/@_benaston/lesson-1b-javascript-fundamentals-380f601ba851) or perhaps [this one](https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600).

Comment: Your answer is correct, I already suspected and knew that this was definitely the case, but just wanted to confirm it.  Every thing that isn't primitive is basically a reference value in js.